# Change button meaning in texmaker

Tags: texmaker, button, keycommand

I am using texmaker on a macbook. It would be very convenient for me if the '$' sign had a single press button.

Is there a way to set texmaker to output '$' if I press '§'? I cannot not go further than the 'Edit User Commands'-menu. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you can make use of the shortcuts in `options`--> `configure texmaker`--> `shortcuts`.

Comment: There is no <code> configure texmaker <\code>? I have it on mac?